Clicking a tagsinput dropdown option causes my menu to close
I am using Mantine as a UI library and I have a send icon button that opens a Menu. This menu then contains a TagsInput component where I can select multiple email addresses.
The problem I have now is that when I select an email in the list (eg Mark@google.com), the entire menu closes down and I have to click the 'Send via email' button again if I want to select more items.
How can I keep the menu open when I click an option in the TagsInput?
CODESANDBOX REPLICATION
The component that handles this action:
import {
  ActionIcon,
  Button,
  Flex,
  FloatingPosition,
  Menu,
  Stack,
  TagsInput,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
} from '@mantine/core';
import { IconSend } from '@tabler/icons-react';
import { useState } from 'react';


function EmailActionButton({ withText = true, position = 'bottom-end' }: EmailActionButtonProps) {
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const options = ['tijl@google.com', 'mark@google.com', 'Jos@google.com'];

  return (
    <Menu width={'min(350px, 100%)'}  position={position}>
      <Menu.Target>
        {withText ? (
          <Button
            leftSection={<IconSend size="1rem" />}
            size="sm"
            variant="light"
          >
            Send via email
          </Button>
        ) : (
          <Tooltip label="Send via email" withArrow>
            <ActionIcon color="gray" variant="light">
              <IconSend size="1rem" />
            </ActionIcon>
          </Tooltip>
        )}
      </Menu.Target>
      <Menu.Dropdown>
        <Stack style={{ position: 'relative' }} p="md" gap="sm">
          <Flex justify="space-between" align="center">
            <Title order={5}>Send via email</Title>
          </Flex>

          <TagsInput placeholder="Select emails" data={options} value={emails} onChange={setEmails} />

          <Button leftSection={<IconSend size="1rem" />} fullWidth>
            Send
          </Button>
        </Stack>
      </Menu.Dropdown>
    </Menu>
  );
}

interface EmailActionButtonProps {
  withText?: boolean;
  position?: FloatingPosition;
}

export default EmailActionButton;



Please see this link. You can control the opened state of dropdown.

I would prefer to have it just handle the outsideclicker to be able to close it.

On mantine Menu you have an option :
<Menu closeOnItemClick={false} > ... </Menu>

It is not written in the menu doc, but somewhere i don't remenber

But what you seems to want to do is an multiselect :)

Thanks, but the closeOnItemClick only applies when you have menuItems, this is different from that. If you try it in the codesandbox the problem will remain the same. And it doesn't matter whether it's a mutiselect or a tagsinput.
I think it's caused because it's another dropdown and every click on an item is considered an outside click of the menu and that shuts it down.
